# Getting Specific Cookie from HttpRequestMessage Response

Tags: c#, httpclient

Could someone help me, I want to get specific cookie value from the HttpRequestMessage Response

Here is my code:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Login(string api, string info, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(api, UriKind.Absolute);

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
            {
                Account account = new Account("email", username, password);
               var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
              var info = JsonSerializer.Serialize(account, options);

                using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(info, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                {
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
                    request.Content = content;

                    var option = HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead;
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await clientWithCookie.SendAsync(request, option).ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> rawCookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
                        return rawCookies;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And these are the Cookies from the response.

```
set-cookie: .GNSAUTH=309B9571FE269F000C96C9CDA2812A56FFD7575B4E0D8512BD67ED2E9FBD41EC0A1139A58977F6113260D3B0A0A4BBB80613AE030CA1E79E0D2BD9CC1582FB8C292FB9105BA333C0F68CD3C54D316DD1BAC631852CE7A5918FE4D2ECF7B6B4CDDE4177C3CC446C93251D60D5BBF80103D293D2BE1A104B4866B278B9EB85E0B67C5180617E0D2E11DEDBE2F3C562704D878FEFDD33D261E2B6B866B2C82E2BED9FA8B4327685C84B8555C59EB9DA70264FBD4D88; expires=Fri, 23-Oct-2020 09:12:10 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax
set-cookie: uid=0d63b942-4d58-40f5-afbd-fe5fa2dfe23b; expires=Fri, 23-Oct-2020 09:12:10 GMT; path=/; secure; SameSite=lax
set-cookie: returnUrl=; expires=Tue, 22-Sep-2020 09:12:10 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax
set-cookie: AKA_A2=A; expires=Wed, 23-Sep-2020 10:12:10 GMT; path=/; domain=tv; secure; HttpOnly
```

My problem is, I can only get the last set-cookie value which is AKA_A2=A; expires=Wed, 23-Sep-2020 10:12:10 GMT; path=/; domain=tv; secure; HttpOnly

How I can get only the first cookie of .GNSAUTH=?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the CookieContainer.
Create a new CookieContainer; Create a new HttpClientHandler which can accept cookies and set the CookieContainer on it.
While instantiating the HttpClient, set this HttpClientHandler on it.

Once the request is made, you can check the cookies in the cookie container.

You can try this:

```
   var container = new CookieContainer();
   HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = true, CookieContainer= container };
   handler.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
   clientWithCookie = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Once the request is successful:

```
    CookieCollection collection = handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://your.base.url"));
    foreach (Cookie item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        Console.WriteLine();
     }
```

Comment: Helloe Sameer. I already done setting up the container and client. But How I can do foreach on response message?

Comment: I can't set the CookieCollection collection = container.GetCookies(uri) to httpresponsemessage. Because I'm using Sendasync

Comment: A small correction above.
As the call is awaited, this should work. Access the cookie container on hander while reading the cookies and pass the base URL of your API while getting the cookies.